# Log4j, не создается файл для логирования

Tags: java, servlet, файловая-система, логирование, log4j

Вот простой пример вызова логера для демонстрации

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@WebServlet(LOGIN_PATH)
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginServlet.class);

    public static final String ERROR_ATTRIBUTE = "error";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("Example log from {}", LoginServlet.class.getSimpleName());
        logger.error("Example log from {}", LoginServlet.class.getSimpleName());
        logger.debug("Example log from {}", LoginServlet.class.getSimpleName());
        logger.warn("Example log from {}", LoginServlet.class.getSimpleName());

        req.getRequestDispatcher(LOGIN_VIEW).forward(req, resp);
    }
    }
```

Для конфигурации я создал  log4j.properties в папке resources

```
# Logger option
log4j.rootLogger = TRACE, console, file

log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%X{CorrelationId}] %-5p %X{method} %X{uri} %c{1} - %m%n

# console is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File = D:\\log\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize = 10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex = 10
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%X{CorrelationId}] %-5p %X{method} %X{uri} %c{1} - %m%n
```

Вот мои зависимости, которые связаны с логированием, в pom xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
      </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
```

Проблема в том, что файл не создается, я вижу только такой вывод в консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файлы не могут создаваться если неверно указан путь.

```
log4j.appender.file.File = log/logging.log
```

Теперь файл будет создаваться в папке `log`, относительно текущей папки.

Вот так будет понятнее

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log/logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize = 10MB 
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex = 10
log4j.appender.file.threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=line:%L - [%-2p][%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%t] %c{5}.%M.%F.%M: - %m%n
```